# How to find volume of a sphere

Tags: volume

what is the volume of a ball that is 5.5 feet tall? I am trying to figure this out but i cannot figure it out with the information given.

Comment: Do you know the formula that gives the volume of a sphere given its radius $R$?

Comment: no i do not know the formula

Comment: Did you try to google "volume of a shpere" or "formula for the volume of a sphere"?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The formula for the volume $V$ of a sphere with radius $r$ is:
$$V=\frac{4\pi r^3}{3}$$
The ball has a diameter of $5.5$ ft. Diameter is twice the radius.

I think you can carry on from here...

Comment: Taking into account your logo, I was almost ready to bet that $\pi$ should be in the formula ! Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

$\cdot$ A really cool way to remember the volume of a sphere is to use the disk method presented in calculus. Namely take upper half of a circle with radius $r$ and the volume of a disk will be given by $V = \pi r^2 dx = \pi (f(x))^2 dx$. Thus integrating over the region on the intervsl $\left[-r,r \right]$ will give you the volume of a sphere. For your problem Height = Diameter = $2$*Radius $\Rightarrow \text{Radius} = \frac{5.5}{2}$.

$$ (1) \ \ f(x) = \sqrt{r^2-x^2} \Rightarrow V = \pi (r^2-x^2) dx,\Rightarrow V_{sphere}= \int_{-r}^{r}  \pi(r^2-x^2)\  dx = \frac{4 \pi r^3}{3}$$

Comment: I don't think someone don't know $4/3\pi r^3$ can understand integration...

Comment: Maybe some day the OP will return or remember seeing this in his/her later days.